# ASP.NET Core Get Request Body from ActionExecutedContext ActionFilter

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to get the body of a POST Request in an ActionFilterAttribute. The bodyString is returned empty without getting any exceptions. I am testing this with a simple { "name": "value" } JSON.

```
public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        string bodyString = string.Empty;

            using (System.IO.MemoryStream m = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
            {
                try
                {
                    if (context.HttpContext.Request.Body.CanSeek == true)
                        context.HttpContext.Request.Body.Position = 0;

                    context.HttpContext.Request.Body.CopyTo(m);

                    bodyString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(m.ToArray());
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    base.OnActionExecuted(context);
}
```

Comment: please show your POST request

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why the MemoryStream cannot read the data because it has already been read by [FromBody] from my method:

```
[HttpPost]
[ServiceFilter(typeof(ETagFilter))]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody]JToken body) 
{ 
    //Do something with the data
}
```

To access the body in the ActionFilter I used:

```
var bodyString = context.ActionArguments["body"];
```

Comment: and ETagFilter ?

Comment: ActionArguments is the part of ActionExecutingContext not ActionExecutedContext